# Helvetica-Light in Beamer disrupts the math fonts

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex

I am trying to make the font of a Beamer presentation match that of a co-author who is using Powerpoint. The Powerpoint font is Helvetica Light.

In XeLatex I used `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{...}`,
as well as a `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`.

This seems to work.  EXCEPT THAT, the math fonts are now broken:
anything that was in `\mathbf{}` appears to be transformed to HelveticaLight also.
Whereas math that is not `\mathbf` looks "normal" (I think serif, CM font).  Inconsistent and ugly!

How can I cause the `\mathbf{}` symbols to look as they would if I had not
requested the helvetica font?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}     % does not seem to work
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{HelveticaLight.ttf}
\usepackage{beamerprosper}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide} { Bad Fonts Mixture }
Here is the problem:
\[
   \sum_k (d_k - \mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{x})^2
\]
The $\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{x}$ is in helvetica light and looks bad next to the $d_k$.
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With LuaLaTeX (or may be XeLaTeX in case you use that) comment `\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}` and use `\setsansfont` instead of `\setmainfont`; that works for me. However, if you want to ensure that math is not touched by `fontspec` you should load it with `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`.

And, in case you use pdfLaTeX, don't use `fontspec` (nor `\setmainfont`) and it should work (although not *light*).

Answer (score 1):

load XITS Math and use `\mathbfit`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Helvetica Neue Light}%% The name of the otf version
\usepackage{beamerprosper}
\begin{document}

\begin{slide} { Bad Fonts Mixture }
Here is the problem: 
\[
   \sum_k (d_k - \mathbfit{b}^T \mathbfit{x})^2
\]
The $\mathbfit{b}^T \mathbfit{x}$ is in helvetica light and looks bad next to the $d_k$.
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

[image]